# issue with including a dplyr::filter in a function

Tags: function, dplyr, filter

I am having trouble with creating a function that includes a `filter()` function.

I keep getting an error (shown below) with this function:

```
plot <- function(df, group, varx, vary) {
  df %>% 
    filter(PC == group) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(get(varx), get(vary)), y = get(vary))) + 
    geom_col() 

}
```

> ```
> Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
>   no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"
> ```

Anyone have an explanation/solution? Thanks!

Comment: To help us to help you, would you mind providing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: From the error message it is almost clear that `df` is a character instead of a dataframe. Also, what are you trying to achieve with `get()`?